# how to print out a string in a button

Tags: objective-c, ios, uibutton

I am trying to make tic tac toe for iphone

and i want if the user press the a button

it shows the user 'X' or 'O' ,

so how to show the string in the button

i tried to type this code

```
NSString *sign =[ sender titleLabel];
NSString *buttonSign=[sign initWithFormat:@"X"];
```

but it failed !

Answer (score 0):

```
sender.titleLabel.text = @"X";
```

Comment: I'm assuming your button is linked to some function for it's "Touch Up Inside" event? And my code is in the body of that function? Please verify your connections in XCode and make sure this is the case. Add `NSLog(@"%@", "Button was pressed.");` in the function and check the output.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method:

```
- (void)setTitle:(NSString *)aString
```

So for example:

```
[button setTitle: @"X"];
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to set the title of a button, you need to set the text like this:

```
[sender setTitle:@"X" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set title by your requirement

for normal state:

```
[mybutton setTitle:@"yes" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

for Highlighted state:

```
[mybutton setTitle:@"no" forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

for selected state:

```
[mybutton setTitle:@"ok" forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```